# Saving as PDF through VBA corrupts the file

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have a hard time identifying this issue. I have a macro that selects multiple sheets within a workbook and saves it as a PDF. The file is placed correctly into the folder and *sometimes* it even opens correctly. However, most of the time the PDF is corrupted and gives me the following error.

[image]

I cannot replicate instances when it works. *The sheet "MSPG Chart" is a chart sheet, i.e. I moved a chart to its own sheet called "MSPG Chart*". If I manually save the file it works.

Below is the code I use:
`NewPathAssembly` is my save path, which works as intended.

```
Sub Create_PDF_StandAlone()

Dim NewPathAssembly as String, Name as String
Dim PDFName as Variant

On Error GoTo ErrLine

NewPathAssembly = "C:\"
Name = "B2110 - xx_30 - MS Peergroup"
PDFName = InputBox("Enter PDF name here.", "PDF title", Name)

   Sheets(Array("Overview", "MSPG Chart")).Select

    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, PrToFilename:= _
    NewPathAssembly & PDFName & ".pdf"

Sheets(1).Select


Exit Sub

ErrLine: MsgBox "Please close the current PDF file"

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the Code 3 times for different sheets. Not even once it showed the Error. Can you share the file in which it shows the Error, as it will be difficult to rectify it if we are not able to replicate it.

Comment: An opinion, if you want to save some string in a Variable, don't use `Default` as it is a Keyword. Change it to `defa` or `nm` etc.

Comment: @mikku I think I was just overzealous declaring my variables. I removed the declaration, since as you said it is a keyword used in the `InputBox`, which works as intended in this setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the argument `ActivePrinter:="Microsoft Print To PDF"`
 worked. It appears that since it defaulted to another printer it somehow corrupted the file.